# Regex match Pattern through Characters

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, newline, spaces

I have a Pattern: `(^([-]?\d+([.]\d+)?,){6}([10],)([-]?\d+([.]\d+)?)$`) which matches: `"26.9841,300.007666,4,1,0,15,1,0"` this is what I want, however my pattern does not match the following Strings:

1. `"26 . 9841,300 . 007666,4,1,0,15,1,0"`
2. `"26.9841\n,300.007666\n,4,\n1,0,15,1,0"`
3. `"2 6 . 9 8 4 1 ,\n 3 0 0 .0 0 7 6 6 6 , 4 \n, 1 , 0 , 1 5 , 1 , 0"`

Which is the exact same String just with random Spaces and New Lines thrown in.

I could match those with the following Pattern:

```sh
(^([-]?\s*?\n*?[0-9 ]+\s*?\n*?(\s*?\n*?[.]\s*?\n*?[0-9 ]+\s*?\n*?)?\s*?\n*?,\s*?\n*?){6}([10]\s*?\n*?,)(\s*?\n*?[-]?\s*?\n*?[0-9 ]+\s*?\n*?([.]\s*?\n*?[0-9 ]+\s*?\n*?)?)$)
```

Which matches 1, 2, and 3, however this pattern is absurd, most likely can be simplified, and doesn't match all New lines; (it won't match New Line occurrence in [0-9]+ (+) chunks). It's also just slapping "\s*?\n*?" wherever it can.

#### Question

What I want to know is if there is a way to match through those characters. Ignoring their occurrence, as long as you can say, if they weren't there the Pattern would match.

###### Note:

Input String should match: `((Decimal|Int),{6}(1|0),(Decimal|Int))`
If New line characters appear at the end of the pattern assume that no more input can be found.
I cannot remove those characters from the input String as I need to know that they were there.
I do not care about leading or trailing spaces/new-lines
Pattern will always start with `"-"` or `"[0-9]"` (yes 0 can be the first char)
Pattern will always end with `[0-9]`

###### Edit

This Regex works and passes my test suite: `(^(-?\s*[0-9]\s*[\s.0-9]*,){6}(\s*[10]\s*,)(\s*-?\s*[0-9][\s.0-9]*?)$)`

Comment: Use `^-?[0-9][\s,.0-9]*[0-9]$`

Comment: This works however it should match only: `((Decimal|Int),{6}(1|0),(Decimal|Int))`

Comment: Can you use something like [`^(\s*-?\s*(?:\d\s*)+(?:\.\s*(?:\d+\s*)+)?)(?:,(?1)){5},\s*[10]\s*,(?1)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pTurCW/1) where you'd repeat the 1st subpattern with a backreference?

Comment: From top down boxes showcase expected groups (1, 2, 3); your pattern for matching 1 also contains some of 2. [image](https://imgur.com/a/uGAoLAo)

Comment: Worked fine on my end if you'd follow the link given. Do I see different input on the top of your printscreen?

Comment: It fails to match: `"26.9841\n,300.007666,4,1,0,15,1,0"` A new line anywhere else seems to work though.

Using Pattern: `^(\s*-?\s*(?:\d\s*)+(?:\.\s*(?:\d+\s*)+)?)(?:,(?1)){5},\s*[10]\s*,(?1)$` with modifiers `Global` and `Multiline`

[pattern](https://regex101.com/r/GuwL52/1)

Comment: It [matches](https://regex101.com/r/PFlu0f/1) for me.

Comment: That regex most likely would work however it seems Java 8 does not understand what `(?1)` is (I should've tested in Java before hand sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to have a test that is a little more of a validation,
this would be more appropriate.
However, anytime you intersperse white space `\s` construct in a regex that
separates alike clusters `(?:\s*\d)+` when this looks like most of your data,
there is a risk of no way points from which to end the search.
This particular regex might work though.

```
^\s*((?:\s*[-]?(?:\s*\d)+(?:\s*[.](?:\s*\d)+)?\s*,){6}\s*[10]\s*,\s*[-]?(?:\s*\d)+?(?:\s*[.](?:\s*\d)+?)?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/YmKJgW/1
The capture group 1 is a convenience that strips leading white space from the match.

```
 ^ 
 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start)
    (?:
       \s* [-]?  
       (?: \s* \d )+
       (?:
          \s* [.]  
          (?: \s* \d )+
       )?
       \s* ,
    ){6}
    \s* 
    [10] \s* , \s* 
    
    [-]?  
    (?: \s* \d )+?
    (?:
       \s* [.]  
       (?: \s* \d )+?
    )?
 )                             # (1 end)
 $
```